# How do I stop a windows from closing after I raise wx.EVT_CLOSE in wxPython?

Tags: python, python-2.7, events, wxpython

I have a Frame and once the user clicks on the exit button, I want a dialogue box to open and ask him if he really wants to close the window.

So I did:

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnCloseWindow)
```

and then I have the Callback:

```
def OnCloseWindow(self, event):
    dialog = wx.MessageDialog(self, message = "Are you sure you want to quit?", caption = "Caption", style = wx.YES_NO, pos = wx.DefaultPosition)
    response = dialog.ShowModal()

    if (response == wx.ID_YES):
        Pairs = []
        self.list_ctrl_1.DeleteAllItems()
        self.index = 0
        self.Destroy()
    elif (response == wx.ID_NO):
        wx.CloseEvent.Veto(True)
    event.Skip()
```

This works, However, I get the error:

```
TypeError: unbound method Veto() must be called with CloseEvent instance as first argument (got bool instance instead)
```

How do I catch the closeWindows instance of the event that is raised?

Comment: Hmmm, in my code it seems I do not even need it. If I catch the event and do not call `self.Destroy()` explicitly, the window is not closed. I also do not call `event.Skip()`. I either close the window myself or not. And that is it.

Comment: Could you post your code, please? didn't quite understand what you did!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not really need to do that much. If you catch the event and do not call `event.Skip()`, it does not get propagated forward. So if you catch the event and do not call `event.Skip()` or `self.Destroy()`, the window stays open.

```
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.on_close)
        self.Show()

    def on_close(self, event):
        dialog = wx.MessageDialog(self, "Are you sure you want to quit?", "Caption", wx.YES_NO)
        response = dialog.ShowModal()
        if response == wx.ID_YES:
            self.Destroy()

app = wx.App(False)
win = MainWindow(None)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: @G-XP-MIA Note that [the documentation](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.CloseEvent-class.html) advises that you *do* call `Veto` if you don't destroy the window: *"If you don't destroy the window, you should call `Veto` to let the calling code know that you did not destroy the window. This allows the `wx.Window.Close` function to return True or False depending on whether the close instruction was honored or not."*

Comment: @dano Interesting. I have never actually read the documentation for close event.

Answer (score 2):

You want to call `event.Veto(True)`, not `wx.CloseEvent.Veto(True)`. `event` is an instance of `wx.CloseEvent` - that's what you want to `Veto`. Right now you're trying to call `Veto` on the `wx.CloseEvent` class itself, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Calling event.Veto(True) doesn't work. Just tested. When I code that and run the code, as I click on "No" on the dialogue box it closes anyways. The way I was doing it worked but raised an error. But you gave me the answer by mistake, the event is "event". So what I have to call is wx.CloseEvent.Veto(event,True) - and that worked perfectly.

Comment: That's weird, because `event.Veto(True)` and `wx.CloseEvent(event, True)` are equivalent. If one works,  so should the other. Anyway, glad you got it working...